# Deriving the total score probability in basketball

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution

I was reading a paper earlier today (Gabel and Redner 2012) and got stuck following their derivation of the following equation. Their logic goes like this:

- Let the number of possessions per second = $\lambda$
- Let the number of seconds in a game (2880) = $T$
- Therefore, the average number of possessions (per game) = $\lambda T$
- Therefore, P(number of plays in a game = $k$) = $\frac{{e^{ - \lambda T } (\lambda T) ^k }}{{k!}}$ ( = $Poisson(\lambda T))$
- We can also say that the total score ($S$) = $\bar{s} k$, where $\bar{s}$ is the average points per possession. Therefore, $k = \frac{S}{\bar{s}}$

This is the part at which I am stuck. We should be able to find P(total score = $S$) by substituting in the above equation:

$$
P(score = S) = P(plays = \frac{S}{\bar{s}})
$$

$$
P(score = S) = \frac{{e^{ - \lambda T } (\lambda T) ^ {( \frac{S}{\bar{s}} ) }}}{{( \frac{S}{\bar{s}} )!}}
$$

However, the authors of the paper get something slightly different:

$$
P(score = S) = \frac{1}{\bar{s}} \frac{{e^{ - \lambda T } (\lambda T) ^ {( \frac{S}{\bar{s}} ) }}}{{( \frac{S}{\bar{s}} )!}}
$$

Where does this $\frac{1}{\bar{s}}$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I have some discrete distribution $P(k)$ over $\mathbb{N}^0,$ the positive integers and zero, which is normalized so that,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(k) = 1.
$$
Now, I want to approximate a distribution over some quantity $l = \lambda k$ where, in this approximation, I assert that the space of $l$ is $\mathbb{N}^0$. This is an approximation because, in reality, $l$ is not necessarily an integer, but rather, it takes on integer values of $\lambda.$ I define $Q(l) = P(l/\lambda)$ and assert that
$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty Q(l) \approx 1.
$$
Is that approximation correct? Well no, I pulled a fast one over you here. The expression in the summand is identical in both sums, making it *look* like the sum is the same, but I swapped the summation index from under your nose. Now, even though the summand is exactly the same, we're evaluating that summand in $\lambda$ times more places than the initial sum. So in fact, the second sum should be approximately equal to $\lambda,$ not $1.$ In fact, what we should say is,
$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty Q(l) = \sum_{k=0,\frac{1}{\lambda}, \frac{2}{\lambda}, \frac{3}{\lambda}, \dots} P(k).
$$
It's easy to see why the RHS of the above is a terrible approximation of the original sum, and hence, $Q(l)$ is not a good approximation for $P(k)$ when imposing the positive integers over $l$ as an approximation.

This effect is subtle when it comes to discrete sums, but is much easier to see when it comes to integrals. Let's look at this approximation by first, approximating the sum over $P(k)$ into an integral using the reverse of the rectangular approximation, then substituting in $l$ for $k$, and then re-approximating the integral into a sum using the rectangular approximation.
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(k) &\approx \int_0^\infty P(k) dk \\
&= \int_0^\infty P(l/\lambda) d (l/\lambda) \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty Q(l) dl \\
&\approx \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{l=0}^\infty Q(l).
\end{split}
$$

In your case, they're treating the scenario approximately like every point scoring play scores exactly $\bar{s}$ points, however $\bar{s}$ is not necessarily an integer. But I assume they want the approximate distribution over $S$ to treat $S$ as integer. The same problem then applies here. However, keep in mind that they're making *two* approximations. First, that every score grants $\bar{s}$ points, and second, that $\bar{s} k$ is a natural number. My answer above deals with the second approximation. The first approximation is dealt with by allowing us to write $P(S)$ by substituting $k = S/\bar{s}$ in the distribution. In fact, the true distribution of $S$ should be given by $P(S) = \sum_k P(k) P(S \mid k)$ where $P(S \mid k)$ is a binomial distribution over $S - 2 k$ where $S - 2 k$ is the number of goals out of $k$ that are required to have been 3-pointers for the score to be $S.$

Comment: Thank you, this was very clearly explained. I definitely wouldn't have worked this out myself, either.